# how to set ActionListener in a particular section of an image?

Tags: java, graphviz

I have generate a graph with help of graphviz tool. I want to set click listener on a particular node of that graph and do some action.

graphviz tool gives three type of output

1. *.png
2. *.svg
3. *.ps

Please help me to do this.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What have you tried?

Comment: @jzd i want to show some graph. in that graph if user click on any node then it show some information.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a 3rd-party tag library to get the functionality you need.  Try primefaces; they have many good chart components; See here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chartsHome.jsf.